# Loading Delay on offline html page

Tags: jquery, html, delay

I have a overlay delay on my html page, if the page couldnt load fast enough.

HTML

```
<div class="loading" style="display: none; "></div>
```

CSS

```
.loading { 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
    left: 0; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    z-index: 100000; 
    background: url(../img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center white;  
}
```

Script

```
jQuery(window).load(function() {
 //Image Hover Efect
 jQuery(".loading").fadeOut(1000);  
});
```

Any change to get a page load delay to check if the scipt is ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of .load use .ready, like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    //Image Hover Efect
    jQuery(".loading").fadeOut('fast');  
});
```

the .ready function is executed when the DOM is fully loaded.

Greatings.

Comment: The Overlay is displayed while the DOM is loading ... would be useless to execute it at dom ready

Comment: The idea is show the overlay when the page is loading.. and on complete, hide the overlay. By default, the overlay is showing... so, we have to hide the overlay when the page loading is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to slow down the response from the server (or delay it with a breakpoint) to test this feature.

I might suggest thought that you don't do this.  Leave it up to the browser to show the user something while your code loads.  As a user, I often won't wait for your page to load before I start reading.  I also don't care to wait a whole second while your overlay disappears.